# Display all sub category product when click main category in magento?

Tags: magento

Display all sub category product when click main category in magento.

like

```
Sub category name(subcategory 1)

product 1 of sub category 1
product 2 of sub category 1
product3 of sub category 1


Sub category 2
product 1 of sub category 2
product 2 of sub category 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get Sub Categories:-

```
$this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories()
```

Change in:

> template/catalog/category/view.phtml

Get products of sub-categories: [Get Sub Categories and Products](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-sub-categories-and-product-count/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot

Please tell me detail

Comment: Given that chapagain gave you some pretty critical hints on how to get this data, can you explain a little more about what you're stuck on? What is happening with your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
    <?php $collection = $_subSubCategoryObj->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('name', 'asc');?>
    <?php ?>
    <?php foreach($collection as $pc ): ?>
        <?php ?>
        <?php  //$p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_subcategory->getId()); ?>
        <?php  //$p->load($pc->getId()); ?>
        <?php //$data = $p->_data; //print_r($data); ?>
        <li class="mega-li li"><a href="<?php echo  str_replace('.html','',$this->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory)).'/'.basename($pc->getProductUrl());?>"><?php echo $pc->getName() ?></a> </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```